# OpenCL library location on win

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I try to learn OpenCL, in the header I need to include , where can I find "cl.h".
I have installed AMD Kernel Analyzer on Win7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in `include/CL/` , just do a search for `cl.h`